# PHP cURL Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I have a `php curl` with proxy problem.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
$proxylist = file('proxy.txt');
$random_proxy = $proxylist[mt_rand(0,count($proxylist)-1)];
$pinfos = explode(':', $random_proxy);
$proxyipport = $pinfos[0].':'.$pinfos[1];
$proxyuserpwd = $pinfos[2].':'.$pinfos[3];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://google.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxyipport);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $proxyuserpwd);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error: ' . curl_error($ch).'<br/>';
}
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

The format of proxies in `proxy.txt` is `ip:port:user:pass` and all proxies are working.

The problem is when I used `$proxyipport` and `$proxyuserpwd` in `CURLOPT_PROXY` and `CURLOPT_USERPWD`, the curl result threw the error `Received HTTP code 407 from proxy after CONNECT`. However, when I replaced those variables with actual `ip:port`, `user:pass`, it worked as normal. I also did an `echo` of `$proxyipport` and `$proxyuserpwd` and it showed me the exact `ip:port` and `user:pass` as expected.

Can someone please tell what I did wrong and how to fix that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it is the newline `\n`, so try:

```
$proxylist = file('proxy.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

If it is another hidden character(s) or a Windows format file then with `\r` you can try:

```
$pinfos = explode(':', $random_proxy);
$pinfos = array_map('trim', $pinfos);
```

Comment: Thank you! There is a hidden character(space?) at the end of each proxy in the list and the `trim()` function solved the problem.